# Where does this Column come from (In Sql Query)?

Tags: soql, api, query, jsforce

I came across a Query that is very useful if I could figure out where a column name is being called from. (So I can edit and repurpose).
The Query is:

```
Select o.Owner.Username, o.OwnerId, o.Account.Name, o.AccountId From Opportunity o where o.AccountId in ('AAAAAAAAAAAA09CV') ORDER BY o.Name
```

which returns

```
{
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Opportunity",
                "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity/OOOOOOOOOOOOWNAS"
            },
            "Owner": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "User",
                    "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/User/UUUUUUUUUUU932LKCL"
                },
                "Username": "testuser@testcompany.com"
            },
            "OwnerId": "UUUUUUUUUUU932LKCL",
            "Account": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Account",
                    "url": "/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/AAAAAAAAAAAA09CV"
                },
                "Name": "My Test Account Company Name"
            },
            "AccountId": "AAAAAAAAAAAA09CV"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, where is ***Owner*** in "o.Owner.Username" coming from? 
And from what I can tell, if you include the relationship fields with the Object Type as well and the API automatically attaches the related object ?

If you could even give a quick run down on how this query is including the associated objects it would be super helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's coming from the Opportunity. You can tell when it says `From Opportunity o`. I'm not sure I follow what else you're asking?

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. Its the "Relationship Name" of the field "OwnerId"

Comment: Sure. It's looking at the owner of the opportunity and able to pull information on the user (as it's a lookup to the user) and for the Account it's able to pull that info as well as there's a lookup to the Account. You can see the field name of both if you look at the lookup fields on Opportunity in `Object Manager` in `Setup`

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Ok, I think I understand it now. Thanks for the quick response and for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply part of how Salesforce handles relationships.

`OwnerId`, the field, indicates a relationship to the `Owner` object (well, the field is owner, the actual object is `User`). It's also not just any relationship, but a *standard* relationship (i.e. one that Salesforce provides, not a custom field)

To get at data on the related object for a standard relationship, the general approach is to just simply drop the "Id" bit of the field API name. `OwnerId` => `Owner`

So to get at the username for the user who owns the Opportunity, we query `Owner.UserName`. We're literally saying "From this `Opportunity`, fetch the user record for the `Owner` of the Opportunity, and find me their `Username`"

The documentation on [Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) goes into more depth. It's focused on SOQL rather than SQL, but the concepts should transfer pretty easily.

Comment: Ok I think this makes sense now. I appreciate the help and nice tip on dropping the Id. I would have probably figured that out eventually after testing but it will definitely help and save me time. Thanks Derek!

Comment: Yes, it's helpful to understand that it's also special in that it's a standard relationship.